# Scroll inside a Windows dialog without first clicking inside the dialog

Tags: windows-8.1, user-interface, mouse-click, mouse-wheel

This might seem like a very insignificant desire but I work on my computer a lot and open a lot of files constantly.

The problem is when I open the Windows 8.1 dialog frame e.g., open, save-as, and there is a scrollpane I have to first click inside the pane before I can use my mouse slider to scroll up and down. Is there a way to avoid clicking inside the pane and have the dialog open up with the mouse activity already inside the pane?

So I could open a dialog box and immediately begin scrolling up and down. I feel like this would make all the difference in keeping up with the flow of productivity.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [katmouse](http://ehiti.de/katmouse/):

> The prime purpose of the KatMouse utility is to enhance the functionality of mice with a scroll wheel, offering "universal" scrolling: **moving the mouse wheel will scroll the window directly beneath the mouse cursor** (not the one with the keyboard focus, which is default on Windows). This is a major increase in the usefullness of the mouse wheel.

KatMouse is free software - however if you like it, you can donate an amount of your discretion

Disclaimer: I have no connection to katmouse other than being a happy user for many years.